# Microsoft botframework bot stopped working in Microsoft team

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I tried to connect a bot built using Microsoft botframework to Microsoft team with no luck.
If I use other channels like webchat it works like a charm ! , I've tried to create new simple bot using Azure Bot services. In a matter of fact, I left the generated echo bot code as is , when I tried to connect to Teams channel I got an error message "Oops something went wrong" as you can see in this screen capture
[Bot Service Azure Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbWJb.png)
tried to use the Microsoft ID and add the bot to MS teams app package however the same behavior applies (bot is never responding)
if the bot is running locally using ngrok there is no message been logged to ngrok endpoint at all as if msteams client is not sending the conversation at all.

I suspect there is a problem with bot registration.

P.S. Skype channel is not working as well.

Thanks,
Amr

Comment: Try going into the bot's settings, changing something, and re-saving. There have been issues with the service that propagates bot settings from Bot Framework to Skype and that might be it. Please report back either way.

Comment: Hi Bill,  I've tried to change the messaging url many times with no luck, created a bot from scratch, nothing
hosted using ngrok , azure bot services, with no luck

Comment: going through existing open issues on github, https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4010 tried the workaround which is "add skype channel as well" found that skype channel is the problematic one , apparently teams rely on skype sync service which seems to fail to sync the settings ,
I'll wait for a while and try again will let you know  Thanks alot

Comment: You shouldn't have to add Skype as a channel.

Are you using a test tenant? Are apps enabled for the tenant? Please see step 5 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant#turn-on-microsoft-teams-for-your-organization

Comment: There was an outage last night that might have impacted you - it should be fixed now but you may have to update your endpoint again. Updates were not reaching Skype which impacts both Skype and Teams.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I can confirm now that it's working fine :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for getting back. I apologize for the outage.